# Question on ExtAudioFileRead and AudioBuffer for iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, core-audio

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses the Extended Audio File Services. I try to use ExtAudioFileRead to read the audio file, and store the data in an AudioBufferList structure.

**AudioBufferList** is defined as:

```
struct AudioBufferList {
UInt32      mNumberBuffers;
AudioBuffer mBuffers[1];
};
typedef struct AudioBufferList  AudioBufferList;
```

and **AudioBuffer** is defined as

```
struct AudioBuffer {
   UInt32  mNumberChannels;
   UInt32  mDataByteSize;
   void*   mData;
};
typedef struct AudioBuffer  AudioBuffer;
```

I want to manipulate the **mData** but I wonder what does the **void*** mean. Why is it void*? How can I decide what data type is actually stored in mData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mData field is marked as void because different audio formats have different storage requirements.

basically in C a void pointer can point to anything.

so you could say

```
mData = (SInt32 *)malloc(sizeof(Sint32) * numElements);
```

and then when you want to use it cast it to the data type you want.

```
Sint32 *myBuffer = (SInt32 *)mData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine size of element in mData array (size of frame) with

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription inputFileFormat;
UInt32 dataSize = (UInt32)sizeof(inputFileFormat);
ExtAudioFileGetProperty(inputFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &dataSize, &inputFileFormat);
size_t sizeOfFrame = inputFileFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
```

Then you can interpret it to any signed type with same size (for usual 4 bytes per frame it can be Sint32 or Float32).